# Get conversion ID and conversion Name when request with Google Adwords Android

Tags: android, google-ads-api

At the moment
When lauch activity i execute this code:

```
        // Google Android conversion tracking snippet
    AdWordsConversionReporter.reportWithConversionId(
            this.getApplicationContext(),
            conversionId,
            conversionLabel,
            this.getClass().getSimpleName(), true);
```

But I don't know how to get converisonId,conversionLabel ? 
Can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

You'll be able to access your conversion ID and conversion label from inside your AdWords account.

Go to the "Tools" tab and select "Conversions" from the drop down.  Click on the conversion tag you are going to be using (you might have more than one so make sure you pick the right one for your app).

Once you have selected the conversion the details will be shown on the "Code" tab once you pick the "I make changes to the code" option (it even gives you a completed code snippet with your values filled in).

If you dont have access to the AdWords account that you're using, ask that someone who does have access but instead of selecting "I make changes to the code", they can pick the "Someone else makes changes to the code" section, where they can then put your email address in and send the details to you.